# Java : Send Multipart File to RESTWebservice

Tags: java, spring, web-services, httpclient, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using **Spring** as Technology. **Apache HttpClient** for calling Webservice. Basic purpose is to upload Multipart File(File is not any image file or video file). but Here **My requirement is slightly different**. Kindly check below image.

[image]

Here You can see first block. It is a simple GUI, having only 2 input tags along with proper form tag.

In second block, There is RESTFul Webservice, which takes Multipart File as parameter and process it. (Upto this it is done). 
Now I am stuck here. I want to send this Multipart File to other RESTFul Webservice which consumes Multipart File only.

code Snippet of RESTFUL Webservice : (Commented some questions, need your suggestion)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/project/add")
public @ResponseBody String addURLListToQueue(
        @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file,
        @RequestParam(value = "id1", defaultValue = "notoken") String projectName,
        @RequestParam(value = "id2", defaultValue = "notoken") String id2,
        @RequestParam(value = "id3", defaultValue = "notoken") String id3){

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/fs/project/add");

// 1) Do I need to convert it into File object? (tried but faced 400 Error)
// 2) Is there any provision to send Multipart File as it is?

MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, "multipart/form-data");
mpEntity.addPart("file", cbFile);


httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
if (resEntity != null) {
  System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
}
if (resEntity != null) {
  resEntity.consumeContent();
}

httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}

}
```

Questions : How to send Multipart File to RESTFul Webservice using HttpClient?

Comment: follow this link.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yr01OEk6FfM

Comment: Are you using CXF or Jersey to build RestFul service?

Comment: @PrafulMakani : I just went through this video. It is not fulfilling my requirement. I want to send multipart file using Apache Httpclient.

Comment: @Garry : I am using Spring 4.0 RestController annotation to create REST Service with the help of STS plugin in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check this [file upload apache http client](http://java.dzone.com/articles/file-upload-apache-httpclient)?

Also

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://echo.200please.com");
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(zipFileName);
File file = new File(imageFileName);
String message = "This is a multipart post";
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();         
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.addBinaryBody
  ("upfile", file, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, imageFileName);
builder.addBinaryBody
  ("upstream", inputStream, ContentType.create("application/zip"), zipFileName);
builder.addTextBody("text", message, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
// 
HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
post.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

[Source](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-multipart-upload)